# Android Wear Record Audio, Failed to start MediaRecoder

Tags: android, wear-os, android-audiorecord

I am writing a audio recorder on android wear by using the mediarecorder class.  This works fine before on android phone. But it doest work well on android wear. 
I can successfully call MediaRecorder.prepare(). But it always failed to on MediaRecorder.start().

Does anyone has some suggestions? Thanks a lot.

```
try {
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(folder + "/XXX" +  ".mp4");
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    Log.d(TAG,"MediaRecorder Get Prepared");

} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.d("timer","Prepare Failed"+e);
    releaseAudioMediaRecorder();
    return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.d("timer", "Prepare Failed" + e);
    //e.printStackTrace();
    releaseAudioMediaRecorder();
    return false;
}
Below are the err messages I received on logcat and the exception I caputred when I call MediaRecorder.start():
 E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -2147483648
 W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
 W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
 W/System.err﹕ at .AudioRecorder.StartRecordAudio(AudioRecorder.java:67)
```

Comment: I am not sure but I seriously doubt that any wear device has an mpeg4 encoder; what exception are you getting?

Comment: @AliNaddaf It just said the mediarecorder failed to start. There is no exception when I prepared the mediarecorder.

Comment: So your log has nothing at all related to this issue? Haven't you set an error listener on your MediaRecorder to receive errors?

Comment: Did you try the anything based on my earlier comment regarding the encoder? Can you try saving the audio without any encoding, say, in wav format?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I have changed method to use AudioRecord instead, since I need to process the audio data anyway. I am writing the audio data into the local file system on the wear. However, the android wear keep giving me "suspending all threads" messages in logcat. It seems recoding audio just cost too much resources? Would it be faster if I send all the data to handheld instead of writing to local files.  Thanks a lot.